# AWS EC2 Ubuntu 14.04 Keeps Timing Out

Tags: amazon-ec2

I've spun up and setup 2 servers now in this AZ and both keep going down shortly after being used. Restarting doesn't fix it and I have to start and stop them.

By going down I mean a timeout error for apache and I can't even SSH. Port 22 is open and I can SSH in once I stop and start the EC2, it doens't run out of memory and only has 2 sites on a t2.medium with the database on RDS.

One of the sites is https://coffeehive.com.au/ if that helps

Any ideas?

Cheers,
Adrian

Comment: You only mention that it doesn't run out of memory. You need to look at all the metrics in CloudWatch for those servers. What does CPU usage look like? What does disk IO look like? What do the CPU credits on those t2 instances look like? From your description it sounds like you are probably running out of CPU credits.

Comment: Nothing fancy, all verging 0 but under 30%

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvq5xyr3cuzx8gm/Capture.PNG?dl=0

I can sit there with Top open and it barely moves then stops access

Comment: I don't see CPU credits in that list. I do see lots of system and instance status check failures, which is really bad. That usually means you need to stop the instance and then start it again so that it is moved to different underlying hardware.

Comment: Oops sorry it cut off:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/xtvp1dofjjvl73n/aws.png?dl=0

I rebuilt the server and now the same thing...either I'm super unlucky or something is up.

It's just Ubuntu, Apache, Magento using RDS all basic nothing fancy

What were your thoughts around CPU Credits as there is a gap

Comment: If cpu credits drop to 0 then your system will become unresponsive. You need to read up on how T2 instances work if that is happening.

Comment: Cpu credits look fine in that graph. If you are getting system status check failures constantly then contact AWS support. That should be a super rare occurrance.